# How do I handle a question where a later book gives the answer?

Tags: discussion

When I wrote [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105016/is-there-any-indication-of-phaedruss-weakness-in-the-reckoner-trilogy) about *The Reckoner Trilogy*, there were only two books. By the time of the accepted answer, the third had been released, which contains the answer, but the answerer chose to write his answer according to the two that had been released to avoid spoiling it. How should I handle this case where the question has been superseded by sequels?

Comment: Radhil updated his answer to include the sequel, so at least that's addressed!

Comment: Dupe of ["What can I do when a question has an old, accepted, and +25 voted **100% incorrect answer** contradicted by canon"](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/what-can-i-do-when-a-question-has-an-old-accepted-and-25-voted-100-incorre?lq=1)?

Comment: @Richard:
Not really... it was correct for the information we had now, and he even added a bit to indicate that there was new info in the third book that definitively answered it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the point of view of an **answerer**:

### Post a new answer.

This is what I've often done in the past: when I find a question whose current answers are outdated and made obsolete by the release of newer material.

E.g. see [Is it true that The Doctor can only regenerate 12 times?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/809/31394) This is one of the oldest questions on the site, and the answers provided in 2011 were all well and good *in 2011*. After the release of Series 8 and 9 in 2014 and 2015, the question was in need of an updated answer, so I posted one. Luckily the OP was still active on the site, and able to change acceptance to my answer instead of an older one. This isn't always the case; sometimes you find a question with outdated or non-canonical answers, provide a perfect answer with nice canon quotes, and it languishes at the bottom of the list because nobody ever notices it and the OP never accepts it. This problem has [been](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/is-it-acceptable-to-edit-in-this-answer-is-wrong-header-into-a-wrong-but-upvot) raised [before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7719/what-can-i-do-when-a-question-has-an-old-accepted-and-25-voted-100-incorre) on meta, with no entirely satisfactory solution found.

---

From the point of view of an **asker** (if you don't want to follow the above advice and self-answer):

### Start a bounty.

One of the possible 'bounty notices' you can put on a question is:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

[image]

Comment: Alas, there is no way to post a bounty on your own (new) answer to an old question.